# Oracle Linux 7.8 - NFS Permission Denied

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, fstab, zfs

I mounted an NFS to my new server (ZFS to NFS).

But I'm getting permission denied when I try to go directory.

All platforms are Oracle Linux 7.8

/etc/fstab:

```
IP_OF_ZFS:/ZFS_PATH/ZFS_PATH     /OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH    nfs rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,tcp,actimeo=0,vers=3     0       0
```

/etc/mtab:

```
IP_OF_ZFS:/ZFS_PATH/ZFS_PATH     /OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=0,acregmax=0,acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=IP_OF_ZFS,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=IP_OF_ZFS 0 0
```

/etc/exports:

```
/OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH IP_OF_ZFS (rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

Mount command:

```
mount -t nfs IP_OF_ZFS:/ZFS_PATH/ZFS_PATH     /OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH -o rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,tcp,actimeo=0,vers=3
```

Mounted successfully:

```
[root@hostname ~]# df -hP
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
IP_OF_ZFS:/ZFS_PATH/ZFS_PATH                50T  2.6T   48T   6% /OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH/OS_LEVEL_PATH
```

But it gives permission denied error.

OS level error:

```
[root@hostname ~]# cd /OS_LEVEL_PATH_1/
[root@hostname OS_LEVEL_PATH_1]# ls -ltrh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 oracle oinstall 22 Dec 28 18:00 OS_LEVEL_PATH_2
[root@hostname OS_LEVEL_PATH_1]# cd OS_LEVEL_PATH_2
[root@hostname OS_LEVEL_PATH_2]# ls -ltrh
total 8.5K
drwx------+ 4 1001 grid 24 Jan 20 12:23 OS_LEVEL_PATH_3
[root@hostname OS_LEVEL_PATH_2]# cd OS_LEVEL_PATH_3
-bash: cd: OS_LEVEL_PATH_3: Permission denied
```

When I try to go OS_LEVEL_PATH_3 with oracle, grid or root. It gives permission denied.

How can I solve this error?

Regards,

Comment: Have you exported/shared the ZFS filesystem on the server? Which export options did you use? Often the "root_squash" option is the default: it means the root account of the NFS client system will be treated as user "nobody" by the NFS server.

Comment: Hi @telcoM, our /etc/exports file like this: /path/path/path IP (rw,sync,no_root_squash)

Answer (score 0):

You're using NFS version 3, so the users are identified by UID/GID numbers. Even with the `no_root_squash` export option, the `root` user of the NFS client host won't necessarily have any special significance for the NFS server host: on this NFS share, the `root` of the NFS client may only be able to access directories and files strictly according to the permissions, so `root` must have access granted to it just like any other user.

The `OS_LEVEL_PATH_3` directory is owned by UID 1001 on the server. That UID has no corresponding user on the client, and there is an ACL on that directory, as identified by the `+` sign at the end of the permissions string. Run `getfacl /OS_LEVEL_PATH_1/OS_LEVEL_PATH_2/OS_LEVEL_PATH_3` to view the full ACL.

Unless the ACL grants access to other users, only an user with UID 1001 will be allowed to access the `OS_LEVEL_PATH_3` directory. You should run `id 1001` on the NFS server to see which user has UID 1001 there, and either create user #1001 on the client with the same username it has on the server, or modify the ACL of the `OS_LEVEL_PATH_3` directory on the NFS server (using the `setfacl` command if it's Linux, possibly something else if it's a non-Linux system) to grant access to the users/groups that actually exist and have matching UID/GIDs on the client and need the access.

Comment: Hi sir, I detailed my question. Can you please review again?